# Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character (NULL, unicode 0) encountered: not valid in any content

Tags: unicode, web-applications, wildfly

I recentently had a power outage and before the outage my web app and wildfly 10.x local server were working fine. After the power outage I am now getting this error whenever I try and start my server.

```
11:53:19,482 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:357)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character (NULL, unicode 0) encountered: not valid in any content
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructNullCharException(StreamScanner.java:638)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwInvalidSpace(StreamScanner.java:668)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwInvalidSpace(StreamScanner.java:659)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNextAfterWS(StreamScanner.java:834)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2031)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1131)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1154)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
    ... 3 more

11:53:19,484 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
11:53:19,494 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) stopped in 5ms
```

I eclipse, I tried changing my text encoding to UTF-8 (which was changed for some reason I changed it back) 
creating a new server
complete restart of computer.

I have pulled a working version of the app just in case and the same error came up.

Edit: Looks like my standalone.xml got emptied out which could be a core issue, not sure how to retrieve the original one I had

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

So apparently during the power outage wildfly decided to empty its own standalone.xml file (not sure why) so I went to the standalone-xml-history (wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history) and found the most recent non-empty one and just copied it over and it worked